# Javascript return correct time format in textbox contained in gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, format

Im trying to get a time entered in a Textbox to autocorrect itself should it find itself missing the : character.
so 0100 becomes 01:00 when user exits the textbox

it is also contained within a gridview.

This is what I've tried but im not getting anything to happen.

```
 function four_digit_clock() 
   {
       var grdvw = document.getElementById('<%= grd_issue_am.ClientID %>');

       for (var rowId = 1; rowId < grdvw.rows.length; rowId++) {
           var txtbx = grdvw.rows[rowId].cells[0].children[0];
           if (txtbx != "" || txtbx.length != 0 || txtbx != null) {
               if (txtbx.length == 4) {
                   var clock = txtbx.value;

                   if (clock.substring(2, 1) != ':') {
                       txtbx.value = txtbx.value.substring(0, 2) + ':' + txtbx.substring(2, 2);
                   }
               }
           }
       }  
   }  

 **html**

 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_grd_am_clock_in" onblur ="javascript: four_digit_clock();"/>
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree completely or am I just missing something?

Comment: You probably have some other problem in there as well but `.substring(2,2)` should be `.substring(2,4)`.

Comment: ahhh it shouldn't be (2,4) but you saying it makes me realise its should be (clock.value.length-2,2) to get the right 2 digits. that wouldn't make it not function though.... any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substring works like this `substring(startpos,endpos)`. Note that `endpos` is NOT the same as string length! Example: `a="1234"` makes `a.stringpos(1,3)` -> `"23"`.

So your comment `(clock.value.length-2,2)` is still wrong. You probably meant `substring(clock.value.length-2, clock.value.length)`.

That also means your `clock.substring(2, 1);` is wrong. (It's actually reversable: `clock.substring(1, 2);` is the same thing!.) What you want is `clock.substring(2, 3);`. (Assuming a string like "15:30").

---

Next to make things simpler. You can use the `this` keyword to target the textbox: I would probably do something like this:

```
 onblur="this.value=four_digit_clock(this.value);"
```

and

```
function four_digit_clock( val ){
   if (val.length < 4 || val.substring(2,3) == ":" ) {
       return val;
   }
   return val.substring(0, 2) + ':' + val.substring(2, 4);
}
```

I haven't tried this in a c# context, but the javascript works. http://jsfiddle.net/mg4gwkmb/

Comment: Works Perfectly, Thank you